# Size/length of a trackbar name in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, trackbar

When I try the following code:

```
namedWindow("My Window");
createTrackbar("Crop my picture", "My Window", &crop, 239);
```

the Track bar name that it is created in "My Window" looks like this:
"Crop n...re"

How can i do to show the complete name?

Thanks

Comment: OpenCV Highui module is intended for debugging purposes only. If you need some good looking GUI, you should use a GUI library (e.g. Qt). It's pointless to make Highgui stuff looking good.

Comment: Thanks for the answer
I thought that being able to show a three words name did not fall into good looking GUI, :-)

Any other idea anyone?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the window that you've created your trackbar on is too small, especially if you're showing a small Mat object on that window.

Create a new window:

```
namedWindow("My_Window",WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
```

This way, you'll be able to maximize it

Comment: The length of the trackbar text does not change, so i can still only see "Crop n...re"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\n` to insert a line break. It helps a little, but not too much, as you can see in the example below: the third label was set to `"gamma\nconstant"`.

[image: screenshot of opencv GUI element - trackbar label]

(Note: I'm using opencv 3.4.2 in python 3.6.)